# Pagination - Always returns ALL the records in the database

Tags: php, mysql

(a) I have Pagination code **BEFORE** I ask my query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

The $total_pages is counting **ALL** the records in the database ALL THE TIME,  because the code listed above is counting ALL the pages **BEFORE** I make the query - I want the records counted AFTER the results of the query, and get the proper number of pages out of those results.

After a series of code lines for my SELECT statement, , my query ends like this ( which is working fine - except for Pagination problems outlined above).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Following the above, the rest of the Pagination code follows, as well as query results. They all work. It's those 3 first lines counting ALL the database pages BEFORE my query that is the problem.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to offer me !

Comment: Pro Hint: Don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are antiquated. Use PDO.

Comment: So apply the same filter you have on the result set to the `COUNT(*)` call and all should be good? If you're only selecting results based on `WHERE foo-bar, then apply that to the count call...

Comment: Don't fully understand the question. Usually you want to know the total number of records in the table, as you've outlined in your first code block, so that you know how many pages you'll need for the UI. If you want to know how many records were returned, you can just iterate over your result and count them.

Comment: what is qryWhere? that would help....

Comment: I explained above - I didn't know "how to" - My ignorance - my apologies...

Comment: All code is presently working when queries submitted. - I just get 59 records PAGINATED every time - even after making any number of individual selections - I want to just get the selected # of records - Try: Category (Indie or Library) and Genre (Rock or Latin or Blues) - Thank you for your help !!!!!!

Comment: Why not query in the previous unfinished question?

Comment: I did, but I did not know how to address the original poster -   - Due to my lack of knowledge, some really short answers totally go over my head !!... I'm greener than grass....

Comment: I tried the below listed answer, the PAGINATION still returns 5 pages - The selected results and all the rest of the records - try clicking on 1 2 3 4 5 6 paged result. Shouldn't some results stop at say page 2 or something like that - due to only 17 records found - for example?? THANKS !!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the total number of results (not just the amount your displaying at any one time), you can run this query AFTER you have run your 'SELECT * FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit' query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

That will tell you the number of matching rows, regardless of the limits you applied to the intial query.

---

If you want to find out how many rows you have pulled out in the last query instead, try modifying it to:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) as total FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit
```

This effectively creates a new column in your results with the total results your pulling out with the limits applied. (I'm assuming you have a column called 'id', if not, use a different column name for the count.

Comment: If you use fetch_array, the found_rows will be in 0 - if thats what you meant.

Comment: LIKE THIS?: $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$total_pages = SELECT *, COUNT(id) as total FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit;

Comment: Is this in reference to the first half of my reply - or second half. I'm still not clear as to which one you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

FOUND_ROWS() only works if you've done a select query with the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` modifier. Otherwise it just returns 0:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM $tableName $qryWhere LIMIT $start, $limit;";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$found = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();") or die(mysql_error());
```

$result would contain only the rows specified in your limit clause, while $found will contains how many rows WOULD have been found without the limit clause at all.

Comment: I tried this, the PAGINATION still returns 5 pages - The selected results and all the rest of the records - try clicking on 1 2 3 4 5 paged result. Shouldn't some results stop at say page 2 or something like that - due to only 17 records found - for example?? THANKS !!!!